# What is the largest species of polychaete?

Tags: zoology, invertebrates

My Google searches seemed to avail no results. My question is: **What is the largest living species in the class Polychaeta?**

That's about it. I understand that there will be few accessible weights for these worms so length will suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Smithsonian](https://web.archive.org/web/20140620040001/https://invertebrates.si.edu/Features/families/polychaeta.html):

> The longest of all known polychaetes was found in Port Jackson, Australia. It was a member of the family Eunicidae, consisted of approximately 1,500 segments and was nearly 6 meters long when alive.

The [Eunicidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eunicidae) consist of numerous species (including the super cool [bobbit worm](https://i.imgur.com/LfXGilj.gif)), many of which get fairly large.

[image]

Though, typically 3 m in considered quite large for worms in this group (e.g., see [Uchida et al. 2009](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/179218/1/Kuroshio.Bio_5_9.pdf) for a description of a 3 m long *Eunice aphroditois*).

[*Polychaetes & Allies: The Southern Synthesis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rin4l7QZ1YEC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=Eunicidae+6m#v=onepage&q=Eunicidae%206m&f=false) also suggests that members of Eucinidae can reach 6 m in length. From p. 94 of this report from the Australian Biological Resources Study:

> Eunicids have many segments and may attain a length of up to 6m...
>
> ...Eunicids range from less than 10cm to 6m in length, and consists of up to 1500 segments (Fauchald 1992a).

Supposedly, according to [Schulze 2011](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e78/b37598d655b679c2d3d606b613d00f36509b.pdf):

> The Australian museum even holds a specimen that reportedly was nearly 6 m long when
> collected (Fauchald 1992 and pers. comm.)

[Salazar-Vallejo *et al.* (2011)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6919/8022753740cb0cb43010d049e43f908d21f7.pdf) also cite evidence of 3+ m long polychaetes in the genus ***Eunice*** as evidence that the genus is "the largest polychaete species and placing them among the longest benthic invertebrates."

---

None of these worms compare to a species of ribbon worm (phylum [Nemertea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemertea)) called [*Lineus longissimus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineus_longissimus) that can reach 55 m in length! [Sources: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineus_longissimus), [2](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/gigantic-extinct-worm-with-impressively-large-jaws-discovered-in-canada/)].